# WP Categories List to be Displayed Ascending Order or by IDs

Tags: php, wordpress

Categories are Listing in random positions, It's needed to be Display According to their Ids, I am posting the code  below for review

Site is in Wordpress and file is lib/all_categories.php

It should Be Listing like this:

```
Category Line A
-----Category 1
-----Category 2
-----Category 3
```

Answer (score 0):

[get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) could help you in this, you can order it by whatever you wants

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', array(
        'orderby'    => 'term_id',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => 0
    ) );
```